# NDepend query methods/types in framework assembly being used by other assemblies/types

Tags: ndepend, cql

I am trying to determine which types or methods in a base framework assembly are being used by other assemblies in the application system. I cannot seem to find a straight-cut query to do that.

What i have to do is first determine which assemblies are directly using the framework assembly, then manually list them in a second query

```
SELECT TYPES FROM ASSEMBLIES "IBM.Data.DB2"
WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "ASSEMBLY:FirstDirectUsedByAssebmly"
OR IsDirectlyUsedBy "ASSEMBLY:SecondDirectUsedByAssebmly"
OR IsDirectlyUsedBy "ASSEMBLY:ThirdDirectUsedByAssebmly"
OR IsDirectlyUsedBy "ASSEMBLY:FourthDirectUsedByAssebmly"
```

Is there a better/faster way to query for this?

Additionally, the query results are focused on the matched types only. The Dependency graph or matrix exported only shows details of those. I do not know how to render a graph that shows those types or methods *plus* show the dependent types/methods from other assemblies that are consuming them?

**UPDATE**

I cannot use a query like

```
SELECT METHODS/TYPES WHERE IsPublic AND !CouldBeInternal
```

because the results return very queer results of using obfuscated types within the IBM.Data.DB2 assembly.

```
SELECT TYPES
FROM ASSEMBLIES "IBM.Data.DB2"
WHERE IsPublic AND !CouldBeInternal


48 items 

--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
types                                             |# IL instructi|
                                                  |ons           |
--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+m                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+x                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+f                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+ac                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+aa                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+u                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+z                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+e                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+b                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+g                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+ab                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+h                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+r                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+p                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+ad                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+i                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+j                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+t                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+af                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+k                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+l                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+y                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+a                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+q                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+n                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+d                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+c                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+ae                                |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+o                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+w                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+s                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.ae+v                                 |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command                           |2 527         |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection                        |3 246         |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataAdapter                       |520           |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataReader                        |4 220         |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2_UDF_PLATFORM                     |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Enumerator+DB2EnumInstance        |19            |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Enumerator+DB2EnumDatabase        |15            |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Error                             |98            |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ErrorCollection                   |55            |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception                         |185           |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Parameter                         |1 853         |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection               |1 383         |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2RowUpdatedEventHandler            |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2RowUpdatedEventArgs               |14            |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Type                              |0             |
                                                  |              |
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2XmlReader                         |500           |
                                                  |              |
--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
Sum:                                              |14 635        |
                                                  |              |
Average:                                          |304.9         |
                                                  |              |
Minimum:                                          |0             |
                                                  |              |
Maximum:                                          |4 220         |
                                                  |              |
Standard deviation:                               |868.22        |
                                                  |              |
Variance:                                         |753 808       |
                                                  |              |
--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Our code does not use those types and enums directly.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the methods (respectively the types), that are public and could not be internal. Hence, it returns the methods/types that are indeed used outside of their declaring assembly.

```
SELECT METHODS/TYPES WHERE IsPublic AND !CouldBeInternal
```

Comment: I have seen that query before, and I have updated my question to explain why it does not work out as expected.